# Problemas al recargar Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, datatable

Saludos a todos, tengo este problema con una tabla Datatable la cual en mi archivo .JS la declaro al inicio de esta manera:

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function(){
     table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: "",
        'rowsGroup': [0,1,3],
        'scrollY': "200px",
        'scrollCollapse': true,
        'paging': false,
        'scrollX': true,
        language: {
            url: 'js/Spanish.json'
        }
    });
});
```

El punto es que luego, dentro de una función la cual va a ocuparse repetidas veces quiero vaciar esta tabla, cargarla de datos con un array llamado myData2 y luego recargar la tabla, pero no sé como hacer que esto funcione... el código comentado dentro del resultado de la funcion es el que antes usaba para cargarlo de una sola vez y funciona correctamente, pero no sé cómo hacerlo para cuando quiero recargar los datos de la tabla del mismo array con diferentes datos:

```
   function cargarTabla(am){
    $("#cargando").dialog("open");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "PruebaController.php",
        data: { accion: 1, am: am }
    }).done(function(data) {
        try {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (obj.error == 0) {
                myData2 = [];
                $.each(obj.arreglo, function(value) { myData2.push(this)});
                $(document).ready(function(){


                    // ESTAS 3 LINEAS DE CÓDIGO SON LAS QUE QUIERO CORREGIR Y HACER FUNCIONAR //

                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(myData2);
                    table.ajax.reload();
                    // var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    //  data: myData2,
                    //  'rowsGroup': [0,1,3],
                    //  'scrollY': "200px",
                 //        'scrollCollapse': true,
                 //        'paging': false,
                 //        'scrollX': true,
                 //        language: {
                    //         url: 'js/Spanish.json'
                    //     }
                    // });
                });
                $("#cargando").dialog("close");
            } else {
                $("#cargando").dialog("close");
                mostrarError(obj.msg);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            $("#cargando").dialog("close");
            mostrarError(msg.err1);
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $("#cargando").dialog("close");
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) mostrarError(msg.err0);
        else if (textStatus === 'timeout') mostrarError(msg.err99);
        else mostrarError(msg.err1);
    });
}
```

Comment: pero la quieres recargar desde un boton o algo asi? o cuando se termine de cargar la pagina? o con un setinterval?

Comment: Creo q la forma de hacer q se recargue la pagina es borrando la tabla y volviendola a crear en el DOM.

Comment: Pero... borrar la tabla y volverla a crear haria que la tabla desapareciera por un instante... no? Siendo asi creo que no me sirve esa solución.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a mi pregunta, logré hacer que funcione de la siguiente manera:

```
table.clear();
$.each(obj.arreglo, function(value) { table.row.add(this).draw()});
```

Comment: DataTables tiene una función reload, que la puedes llamar cuántas veces necesites

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haria de la siguiente forma:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#example').DataTable({        
            'rowsGroup': [0,1,3],
            'scrollY': "200px",
            'scrollCollapse': true,
            'paging': false,
            'scrollX': true,
            language: {
                url: 'js/Spanish.json'
            },
             'ajax': {
                    'url': 'Controller.php',
                    data: { accion: 1, am: am },
                    'dataSrc': 'data', // este es el indice del arreglo json retornado, que contiene los datos
                    'cache': false
                },
        });
```

y cada vez que necesite recagar el dataTables, simplemente hacer: `table.ajax.reload();`